# How to create a map like the one used on the drupal.org homepage?

Tags: google-maps

I want to know how to create an interactive map like the one used on the home page of drupal.org.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful: [How the Drupal.org home page map works](https://association.drupal.org/node/784)

This is the actual module: [HTML5 user geolocation](http://drupal.org/project/html5_user_geolocation)

Comment: Thank you very much i will test it and give you a feedback